# Showing an ideal is principal.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Is $(x-1,y-1)$ a principal ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$?

What I've reduced this to is -

$$0 = y^3-x^2 = y^3-1+1-x^2$$

Hence $(y-1)(y²+y+1)=(x-1)(x+1)$

I also know that $x+1$ doesn't belong to the maximal ideal $(x-1,y-1)$.
Is there a way to say it is actually a unit?

Comment: The ring is iso.orphoc to $\mathbb{C}[t^3,t^2]$

Comment: Yeah. But how does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is wrong

> > As mentioned in the comment the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t^3,t^2]$ think about $t^2+t+1$ and $t+1$ which are relatively prime . You have $t^2+t+1-t(t+1)=1$ did you figure out?
> >     $x^2=y^3$ WHICH also means $\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt{y}$
> >     $(x-1)(x+1)=(y-1)(y^2+y+1)$
> >     $(x-1,y-1)=(\sqrt{y}-1)$
> >      to see this first $(\sqrt{y}-1)(\sqrt{y}+1)=(y-1)$ 
> >     and 
> >     $(\sqrt{y}-1)(y+\sqrt{y}+1)=\sqrt[3]{y^2}-1=x-1$ to see the other inclusion. 
> >     $x-1-\sqrt{y}(y-1)=\sqrt{y}-1$ Hence the
> >      ideal $(x-1,y-1)=(\sqrt{y}-1)$ but the later is not in our ring so the ideal is not principal. It is easier to see that in terms of $t$ because the ideal $(t^3-1,t^2-1)=(t-1)$ but the later is not in $\mathbb{C}[t^3,t^2]$ so it is not principal.

As Arthur pointed out my solution does not make sense because the ideal is not the same in the bigger ring. Solving that in $R=\mathbb{C}[t^3,t^2]$ is easier suppose on the contrary  the ideal is principal $(t^3-1,t^2-1)=(f(t^3,t^2))$ then we get $f\mid t^3-1 $ and $f\mid t^2-1$. But $f\in R$ so it is degree is at most $2$. Also we know that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraicly closed so $t^3-1, t^2-1$ factors completely and $1$ is the only common root between them. Hence the only option for $f$ in $R$ is to be a unit or $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding. You want to show that x+1 is an unit like I said? Or is this an independent proof?

Comment: @user454200 is that clear?? If it is accept the answer then

Comment: This argument is rather weak. Just because an ideal is generated by some element outside our ring, that doesn't mean it _can't_ be generated by some element in the ring as well. For instance, in $\Bbb Z$, the ideal $(4, 6)$ can be seen as "generated" by $\frac23$, but $\frac23$ is not in $\Bbb Z$. Still, it is a principal ideal as it is also generated by $2$. In the same way, just because $(t^3-1, t^2-1)\subseteq \Bbb C[t]$ is generated by $(t-1)$, that doesn't by itself imply that it's non-principal in $\Bbb C[t^2, t^3]$

Comment: @Arthur your example is false because I showed $(t^3-1,t^2-1)=(t-1)$ but it is not the case in yours $(4,6)=(2)$ in  the $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ where 3 is a unit hence $2=2/3$.  My argument is not the usual way I guess but it works . Or is the ideal a principal? In the original ring

Comment: No, your argument does _not_ work as written. What you have is a ring $R=\Bbb C[t]$ and a subring $S=\Bbb C[t^2,t^3]$, and a principal ideal $I=(t-1)\subseteq R$. Then you argue that because your chosen principal generator is not contained in $S$, the ideal $I\cap S\subseteq S$ is not principal. My $R=\Bbb Z[1/3], S=\Bbb Z$ example shows that that reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Okay I see what do you mean the ideal generated by $(t^3-1,t^2-1)$ is not the same in the two rings because in the bigger we multiply with more elements. Thanks I will change the solution

Comment: @Arthur I edited my solution